# Are resized browser windows a real-world use case?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, resize

I'm working on the styling of a site that uses bootstrap 3. The front-end is not my strong suit, and my role is cleaning up small issues.

I develop my work on a desktop at full-width. We're using the bootstrap pre-defined viewports, and I use that in making a responsive design. Then I check the mobile performance and go from there. Then after that I look at tablet layouts, and it's typically fine. My method perhaps isn't best practice, but it's been working so far.

When I show the results of my work to the marketing client, they "test" various layouts by resizing the browser window they're using on the desktop. By doing this, the page elements are reshuffled by the browser, and can end up in odd places at arbitrary viewport widths.

The situation is that I can't re-create these broken layouts by selecting device parameters in mobile modes. It can only be done by opening the site in a full-size browser window, and then resizing it using the mouse to certain, arbitrary widths.

Marketing is thinking this means that the site truly isn't responsive, and we need to develop it so that the layout looks good at any arbitrary browser width, pixel by pixel. Testing resizing windows would be a break from our current development method.

As far as the site end-users, are resized browser windows really a real-world scenario? Is one of our end users going to get a broken layout because they have resized their browser window (not filling their monitor), or have an oddball resolution on their desktop system? Or need we only develop against pre-defined static sizes?

Comment: I don't always have my browser windows fill the monitor. Users will do everything you haven't planned for, and you shouldn't assume that they won't resize their windows to arbitrary sizes.

But doesn't Bootstrap handle much (all?) of the layout for you, even at arbitrary sizes? The question does strike me as not quite an SO fit, though...perhaps workplace or IPS...

Comment: Users may also have their windows set to arbitrary zoom levels, which has comparable effects on content to resizing the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a digital agency I worked for, we asked this same exact question. We set up some analytics on multiple projects to determine how often our end users would resize browser windows. These were relatively basic WordPress websites. In our testing of approximately 500k users, less than one percent resized the window during their sessions.

Is that a high enough number to care about? It depends on the client. Some clients would say, "Less than one percent? We don't care." Others would say "one out of one hundred visitors might see a broken UI?! Unacceptable!"

Unfortunately, in contract work, you are generally held to the whims of your client unless this specific issue is outlined in the contract. A clause such as "Unwanted behavior that accepts less than one percent of the typical userbase is not included in this statement of work" or something like that. Then, you can tell the client that you'll fix it but it'll take an amount of time and money that wasn't accounted for in the original contract.

You could also explain to the client that the issue only happens on resizing, which happens rarely in the real world, and that upon resizing the browser window they should reload the page to see how the end user with a browser of that size would actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, if you use bootstrap properly, it should not really break entierly ever when resizing. While you don´t necessarily rescale your browser Window manually to all the sizes all the time, you can definitely expect users to drag them to the edges of the screen and then resize 2 Windows that way at 1080p, 1440p and 4k. Also, things like Safari on MAC can break things as well. And if it breaks when rescaling, why would not there be a phone size around that also breaks it outright?

But, who are we to tell you whether your site is fine or not. We don´t know how bad, or actually not that bad it is.